# How to Integrate Stripe in Next js 13 application

Tags: javascript, next.js, stripe-payments

I haven't found a solution for integrating Stripe into my Next.js 13 application in order to integrate Pre-build checkout form.

I have attempted to integrate Stripe into my Next.js 13 application, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a solution thus far. If anyone has successfully achieved this integration and can provide guidance or a solution, I would greatly appreciate it. Please feel free to share any insights or instructions you may have.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what didn't work? If you only need to create a Checkout Session, you can use the official node.js library (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node), and then redirect the customer to the returned URL. https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=node

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use node stripe and create a stripe object with your secret key.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_...');
```

In a server component or API route create a `Session` object

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success', // return URL
  line_items: [
    {price: 'price_H5ggYwtDq4fbrJ', quantity: 2}, // what you sold
  ],
  mode: 'payment',
});
```

This is obviously an example, you need to update the call with your needs. See https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=node for details.

Now you can use `session.url` to redirect your user to the built-in checkout in whichever way you want.